# Spelling out the fractional part of a monetary amount using a NumberFormatter in Swift

Tags: swift, string, internationalization, currency, formatter

I need to convert a monetary amount into a string expressing the value in plain text (i.e. cheques, contracts and other legal documents).
This can be done with a `NumberFormatter` that converts numbers in plain text when using the number style `.spellOut`:

```
var curAmount = 10097.43
var fmtAmount : String

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier:"en_US.UTF-8")  // for demo only 
//formatter.locale = Locale.current  // Normal case is user's preferred locale
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
if let fmtAmount = formatter.string(from: curAmount as NSNumber) {
    print ("Amount: \(fmtAmount)")
}
```

It works fine for the integral part of the number, but the fractional part is unfortunately handled as a sequence of independent digits, in all the six languages I have tried.  For example:

```
ten thousand ninety-seven point four three
```

But I need that the fractional part is also expressed as a number, such as

```
ten thousand ninety-seven point forty three
ten thousand ninety-seven dollars forty three
```

I could of course take the string, remove everything after the `"point"`, multiply the fractional part by hundred, generate a second number string and concatenate both strings.  But this would not work with locales using foreign languages, nor with currencies having zero or three digits after the point.

Is there a way to get the fractional part handled correctly as a plain text whole number, out of the box, perhaps using some subtle parameters of the formatter ? And is there a way to include also the name of the currency (i.e. like it is spelled out with number style `.currencyPlural`) at the right place depending on the locale's language?

Comment: What is the currency that has 3 fraction digits? AFAIK all of them have 2 fraction digits or none.

Comment: @LeoDabus There are not so many of them, but apparently there are at least a couple of dinar-currencies that have three digits, e.g. Tunisian [TND](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunisian_dinar) or Kuwaiti KWD, apparently because a dinar is subdivided in 1000 subunits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary remark:** The main problem here, is that I want an internationalized solutino that relies on the build-in iOS/macOS features.  I can therefore not use any solution based on a given decimal separator, as it would change dependeing on the user's locale, nor use hard-coded strings.  This is why I can only upvote Roman's solution for its very elegant code, but not accept it, since it doesn't fully meet the requirements.

```
let value = 12345.678      // value to spell
currency: String? = nil   // ISO currency if you want one specific
```

### 1.Initialize the formatter:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()  // formatter with user's default locale
```

If I want to use a different language,  or a different country formalling, I have to explicitly overwrite the locale:

```
formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US.UTF-8")  // for demo only
```

This works fine, if I use the currency of the locale country.  But if I use another currency, the formatter behavior might e wrong for some formatting styles.  So, the trick is to use a **currency-specific locale**:

```
if currency != nil {
    let newLocale = "\(formatter.locale.identifier)@currency=\(currency!)"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier:newLocale)
}
```

The interesting `Foundation` feature is that when I change the currency,  the currency specific locale settings,  i.e.  the currency code, currency symbol,  and number of digits automatically change:

```
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
let decimals = max(formatter.minimumFractionDigits, formatter.maximumFractionDigits)
```

### 2.Get the full currency name in the right grammatical form

Now I have the `decimals`, but I would like the full name `spelledCurrency` of the currency.  The problem is that some languages have it neutral. For some languages you have to write it singular for 1 unit, but plural from 2 onwards.  For some languages, the decimals matter in the choice between singular and plural.  Fortunately, `NumberFormatter` allows to tackle this with the style `.currencyPlural`.  This weird style write in the numbers in digits, but writes the plain currency according to language specific rules.  It's magic:

The problem is that I want only the name of the currency: no space, no separator, no digits. And I want it to work for Japanese (locale `"ja_JP.UTF-8"`) as well.  Fortunately, we can filter very easily the string:

```
formatter.numberStyle = .currencyPlural
var spelledCurrency : String
if let plural = formatter.string(from: value as NSNumber) {
    // Keep only the currency spelling: trim spaces, punctuation and digits
    // ASSUMPTION: decimal and thousand separators belong to punctuation
    var filter = CharacterSet()
    filter.formUnion(.punctuationCharacters)
    filter.formUnion(.decimalDigits)
    filter.formUnion(.whitespaces)
    spelledCurrency = plural.trimmingCharacters(in: filter)
 }
 else {
    // Fall back - worst case: the ISO code XXX for no currency is used
    spelledCurrency = formatter.currencyCode ?? (formatter.internationalCurrencySymbol ?? "XXX")
 }
```

### 3.Separate the numeric components

I used a `value` defined as `Double`.  But you could easily adapt for the `Decimal` type, whcih is more robust for currencies. The trick is to have the `wholePart` in currency units,  and the `wholeDecimal`, i.e. the part expressed in  an integer number corresponding to the number of subunits of the currency (which is known, thanks to the number of currency's number of decimals):

```
let decimalPart = value.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
let wholePart = value - decimalPart
let wholeDecimals = floor(decimalPart * pow(10.0, Double(decimals)))
```

### 4. Spell out the components

Here we use the native `.spellOut` feature to spell numbers.  That's fantasic if you try to learn foreign languages ;-)

```
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let wholeString = formatter.string(from: wholePart as NSNumber) ?? "???"
let decimalString = formatter.string(from: wholeDecimals as NSNumber) ?? "???"
```

### 5. Final assembly

We now have to assemble the components.  But instead of saying twenty dollars point five seven,  we should say officially twenty dollars and fifty seven cents.  What I've decided is to replace `"and"`  with the localised name of the currency and followed by the number of sub-units, without expressing the subunit itself.  It works in the couple of languages I know:

```
// ASSUMPTION: currency is always between whole and fractional
// TO BE VERIFIED: Ok for Right to left writing?
var spelled : String
if (decimals>0 && wholeDecimals != 0) {
    spelled = "\(wholeString) \(spelledCurrency) \(decimalString)"
} else {
    spelled = "\(wholeString) \(spelledCurrency)"
}
```

Just need to print (or return) the final value:

```
print (">>>>> \(spelled)")
```

### 6. Tests

Here the test results in some langauges:

```
en, USD: twelve thousand three hundred forty-five US dollars sixty-seven
fr, EUR: douze mille trois cent quarante-cinq euros soixante-sept
de, EUR: zwölf­tausend­drei­hundert­fünf­und­vierzig Euro sieben­und­sechzig
nl, EUR: twaalf­duizend­drie­honderd­vijf­en­veertig euro zeven­en­zestig
it, EUR: dodici­mila­tre­cento­quaranta­cinque euro sessanta­sette
es, EUR: doce mil trescientos cuarenta y cinco euros sesenta y siete
ja, JPY: 一万二千三百四十五 円
fr, TND: douze mille trois cent quarante-cinq dinars tunisiens six cent soixante-dix-sept
```

The last test shows a rounding error for `Double`,  so it's better to use `Decimal`.

I also used with amounts between 1 and 2 euros with and witout subunits, and integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways it something like this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier:"en_US.UTF-8")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

let curAmount = 10097.43

let curAmountSplitted = String(curAmount).split(separator: ".") // Splits the number into [String] array of integer and fractional parts of the number
let curAmountStrings = curAmountSplitted.compactMap{formatter.string(from: Int($0) as! NSNumber)} // creates a [String] array by applying a closure to every element of curAmountSplitted array

print(curAmountStrings.joined(separator: " point ")) // joins curAmountStrings with a separator
// prints ten thousand ninety-seven point forty-three
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting suggestion based on another (more elegant) separate handling of the integer and the fractional part. However, it also suffers from the limitation to the English locales, due to the hard-coded  “point” (see paragraph “*I could of course...*”), unless you’d have a way to find out how to spell “point” in the many languages supported by macOS (e.g “virgule” in French or “Komma” in German)

Comment: Another alternative that could be acceptable (at least in all the languages that I know) would be to replace the hard-coded “point” with the name of the currency (using preferably the plural spelling, as in the last paragraph of the question)

Comment: @Christophe It's you who hardcoded "en_US", not me )) Generally, if we talk about Locale, "point four three" for "en_US" is the only right answer, without "forty three". In "ru-RU", for example, .spellOut gives "forty three" (in Russian of course), as it is the way they pronounce the decimal part.

Comment: indeed, I hard coded the locale in this snippet, to produce an example that is understandable and reproducible by everybody, This is why I noted in the comments the normal alternative, where the user’s locale is brought in. I’m not native English speaker, but there are a lot of US tv shows where I can hear “one fifty” and not “one five zero”. I’ll have to check if the rule is different for monetary amounts than for other units. Glad to hear that at least in Russian it’s ok ;-)

Comment: I digged a little bit and could find some serious references that in US english,  the fractional part should be spelled out as whole number (see section 12.20 and 12.9.k of the [US Government Printing Office Style Manual](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016-14.pdf)) or, here: [how to write portions of dollars in a contract](https://legalbeagle.com/5847402-write-dollar-amount-contract.html). Interestingly, the "point" is not a good choice when the numbers have a unit of measure, so the right solution will involve some concatenation like you do